# How to use the gson library from google

Tags: java, android, android-studio-import

I am trying to use the [google gson](https://github.com/google/gson) library in android studio, but I can't import it. I've added the .jar file to the libs folder, and I added

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
```

to my app build.gradle dependencies. There's no option to add library when I right click the .jar file.

Then, is there a package statement I need to write? Or an import?

I'm very new to java, and help is very much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can either compile like the answer below or just simply put the JAR file in the libs folder. That's it. Nothing needs to be added to a build path.

Comment: Thanks, I realized I had the wrong type of file...oops

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should add in your build.gradle, inside the dependencies the following:

```
  compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
```

Then sync project and you will have gson included!

Here is the repo of gson: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.5

Comment: For other people copying this code, make sure to click the link, find the newest version, and replace version 2.8.2 with that version. It's currently 2.8.5 as I write this comment.

Answer (score 0):

in your app gradle add this

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
}
```